# Using Google OAuth2 from Silverlight out-of-browser application

Tags: .net, silverlight, oauth-2.0

I'm planning to access Google's APIs and do authentication using OAuth2. Since I'm going to access them from a Silverlight out-of-browser application I was wanting to know how to keep it secure enough.

I understand that keeping all the details necessary to authenticate on the client is a bit risky. By this I mean the client_id, client_secret, etc. as they could easily be obtained by someone else. So I was wondering how people get round this? Would you use a web service to initally contact Google when authenticating? If so, how can I help keep that secure so only my Silverlight client can access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth client side authentication does not expose any secret information. If you look at [OAuth 2.0 for client-side web applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#CS) you will see that only required information is public client_id.

Comment: That's for web applications rather than for desktop applications as explained futher down on that link - http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#IA

Comment: The key here is client-side part, javascript or silverlight makes no difference. Desktop flow is for applications that can't embed web browser

Comment: The client-side flow seems to require a redirect to a web page though. Are you suggesting I make a web page and redirect to that and then get the code from that?  For instance, in a WP7 app I could then display that page in a WebBrowser control and retrieve the auth_code from the title of the page?  To be honest, I just assumed the desktop flow would be the one I needed if I was doing a Silverlight OOB or WP7 application.

Comment: Yes, you should use WebBrowser control to redirect to google oauth page as described in the link in my post. WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event will have access_token in the fragment. Facebook has better explanation in their OAuth 2.0 documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/